# How to get the timestamp of when a disk is made offline from diskmgmt or other ways in windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, wmi

I want to know the time when a disk is made offline by user. Is there a way to know this through WMI classes or other ways?

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot find a way to do it through the Win32 API/WMI or other, I do know of an alternate way which you could look into as a last-resort.

What about using [NtQueryVolumeInformationFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryvolumeinformationfile) with the FileFsVolumeInformation class? You can do this to retrieve the data about the volume and then access the data through the [FILE_FS_VOLUME_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_fs_volume_information) structure. This includes the creation time.

---

At the end of the post, I've left some resource links for you to read more on understanding this so you can finish it off the way you'd like to implement it; I do need to quickly address something important though, which is that the documentation will lead you to 
an enum definition for the [_FSINFOCLASS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ne-wdm-_fsinfoclass), but just by copy-pasting it from MSDN, it probably won't work. You need to set the first entry of the enum definition to 1 manually, otherwise it will mess up and NtQueryVolumeInformationFile will return an error status of [STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) (because the first entry will be identified as 0 and not 1 and then all the entries following it will be -1 to what they should be unless you manually set the = 1).

Here is the edited version which should work.

```
typedef enum _FSINFOCLASS {
    FileFsVolumeInformation = 1,
    FileFsLabelInformation,
    FileFsSizeInformation,
    FileFsDeviceInformation,
    FileFsAttributeInformation,
    FileFsControlInformation,
    FileFsFullSizeInformation,
    FileFsObjectIdInformation,
    FileFsDriverPathInformation,
    FileFsVolumeFlagsInformation,
    FileFsSectorSizeInformation,
    FileFsDataCopyInformation,
    FileFsMetadataSizeInformation,
    FileFsMaximumInformation
} FS_INFORMATION_CLASS, *PFS_INFORMATION_CLASS;
```

---

Once you've opened a handle to the disk, you can call NtQueryVolumeInformationFile like this:

```
NTSTATUS NtStatus = 0;
HANDLE FileHandle = NULL;
IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock = { 0 };
FILE_FS_VOLUME_INFORMATION FsVolumeInformation = { 0 };

...
Open the handle to the disk here, and then check that you have a valid handle.
...

NtStatus = NtQueryVolumeInformationFile(FileHandle,
    &IoStatusBlock,
    &FsVolumeInformation,
    sizeof(FILE_FS_VOLUME_INFORMATION),
    FileFsVolumeInformation);

...
```

If NtStatus represents an NTSTATUS error code for success (e.g. STATUS_SUCCESS) then you can access the VolumeCreationTime (LARGE_INTEGER) field of the FILE_FS_VOLUME_INFORMATION structure with the FsVolumeInformation variable.

---

Your final task at this point will be using the LARGE_INTEGER field named VolumeCreationTime to gather proper time/date information. There are two links included at the end of the post which are focused on that topic, they should help you sort it out.

---

See the following for more information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryvolumeinformationfile

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ne-wdm-_fsinfoclass

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_fs_volume_information

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724280.aspx

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshpoley/2007/12/19/datetime-formats-and-conversions/

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am looking for the timestamp of "when athe volume is made offline" by user or other means.  FileFsVolumeInformation class only has the creation time.

Comment: @DebjyotiGhoshal I apologize for misunderstanding - is it okay if I leave the above present say on case someone else finds it useful? About the timestamp for when the volume is made "offline" only, I don't think Windows stores that information, but I could be wrong about that.